# window.location.href - Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http-headers

I have a url that my visitors can visit that triggers an instant file download:

```
http://localhost:3000/download
```

Here is the Node.js Express code for this route:

```
router.get('/download', function(req, res, next){
    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=downloadfile.zip');
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/zip');
    var filestream = fs.createReadStream('downloadfile.zip');
    filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

So I'm setting my headers properly and serving up the file for download. In Chrome, if I use JavaScript to trigger this download:

```
window.location.href="/download";
```

Then Chrome's console warns:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/zip: "http://localhost:3000/download".
```

The file is downloaded correctly however. Just that warning shows up. There are dozens of topics on this warning and everything appears to point to making sure that your headers are set correctly. I'm pretty sure mine are correct.

Here are the response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=downloadfile.zip
Content-type: application/zip
Date: Wed, 23 Dec 2015 19:14:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

And here are the request headers:

```
GET /download HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LYZ28E) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.20 Mobile Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:3000/filerequest
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cookie: dwanonymous_259c8c42aa11d4ff581f55a1b8d75159=ablFleC64VDwlUxLnzJvjesSKP; s_fid=3E452B78AEFE8958-0900CA102BA80FF0; com.somthing.iMAWwwee=36335a074-9eds-cbbc-91a4-4b8d238ddw6d6
```

I don't see this error in Firefox. In Chrome I see this error whether or not I have "Ask where to save each file before downloading" checked or not in the Settings.

Is this just a warning I should expect visitors to ignore or is there something I can add to the response headers to prevent this?

Comment: Hi Jake, did you ever figure this one out? Just ignore?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the `Content-Length` header?

```
router.get('/download', function(req, res, next){

    var stat = fs.statSync('downloadfile.zip');
    res.writeHead(200, {
       'Content-disposition' : 'attachment; filename=downloadfile.zip'
       'Content-Type' : 'application/zip',
       'Content-Length' : stat.size
    });

    var filestream = fs.createReadStream('downloadfile.zip');
    filestream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added that but same result.

Comment: Is it an `<a href></a>` link? you can try and add the `download` property. Or give the link the target `_blank`. Basically what is happening is that you are opening the file in the browser.

You can also try to disable all plugins (google docs..etc) from chrome, and see if that works.

Comment: It's no link but it could be. It's just when I even enter it into the address bar, or if it's a link, or if I use JS to get to it.

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins in chrome? And i remember having this issue as well a few months back. But only on one PC. I reinstalled chrome on that PC and the message was gone